# Play lazy writes on recursive option list

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

How to prepare(play framework, scala) Json writes on an option of list of objects, for example

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int, relations: Option[List[Person]])
```

I tried with following writes

```
implicit val personWrites: Writes[Person] = (
    (__ \ "name").write[String] and
    (__ \ "age").write[Int] and
    (__ \ "relations").lazyWrite[Option[Writes.traversableWrites[Person](personWrites)]])(unlift(Person.unapply))
```

It is not working, can someone please help me with correct way of creating these Json writes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are quite close:

```
implicit val personWrites: Writes[Person] = (
  (__ \ "name").write[String] and
  (__ \ "age").write[Int] and
  (__ \ "relations").lazyWriteNullable(Writes.traversableWrites(personWrites)))(unlift(Person.unapply))
```